# Entering Foreign key in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database where I am using an add to cart mechanism. Now I want a particular customer to log in, enter his details and then proceed to the shopping. I'm not sure what my query should be when I want to enter the customer details in the cart table.

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE customer ( 
    Cid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Phone varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Cid) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
CREATE TABLE cart ( 
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    cid int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    pid varchar(11) NOT NULL, 
    quantity int(11) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    KEY cid (cid), 
    CONSTRAINT cart_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES customer (Cid) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query I was previously running without the customer login details was

```
INSERT INTO cart (pid, quantity) VALUES ('".$row{'code'}."', '".filter_input((INPUT_POST), "quantity")."')
```

*here code is obtained from the products table*
Any help on how to Insert the foreign key constraint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After customer login you will get customer id, so update cart table

```
 INSERT INTO cart (pid,cid, quantity) VALUES ('".$row{'code'}."', '".<customerid>."', '".filter_input((INPUT_POST), "quantity")."')
```

You can get the  from session as after login you should store the logged userid in session.

Here is the steps: (please consider the sql injection & safety issue also) 
In file1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$sql = "<your insert query> to insert data in customer table"
$_SESSION["cid"] = mysqli_insert_id();
```

In fil2.php

```
<?php
    $sql = " INSERT INTO cart (pid,cid, quantity) VALUES ('".$row{'code'}."', '".$_SESSION["cid"]."', '".filter_input((INPUT_POST), "quantity")."')"
```

Comment: So should I do it like $_SESSION[cid];

Comment: if you store in session as 'cid', then the answer is yes.

Comment: mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO customer (Name, Address, Phone) VALUES ('$Name','$Address','$Phone')");
    $Cid = $_SESSION["Cid"];
Does this look fine?
But it is generating an error, undefined index cid

Comment: after inserting the customer data you need to fetch the customer id & need to store it in session.To fetch customerid,  you can use mysqli_insert_id() . Thet step will be:  "INSERT INTO customer (Name, Address, Phone) VALUES ('$Name','$Address','$Phone')"); $_SESSION["Cid"] = mysqli_insert_id($con);

Comment: And what if I want to work on two files?
Entering customer details on one file and then accessing the $_session cid in other file? Will php allow me to do so?

Comment: sure...this is the benefit of store data in session, so that you can access the session value anywhere in you site.

Comment: ile1.php INSERT INTO customer (Name, Address, Phone) VALUES ('$Name','$Address','$Phone')"); $_SESSION["Cid"] = mysqli_insert_id($con); file2.php INSERT INTO cart (pid, cid, quantity) VALUES ('".$row{'code'}."','".$_SESSION[cid]."', '".filter_input((INPUT_POST), "quantity")."') Notice: Undefined variable: cid in file2 –

Comment: did you use session_start(); in your main page? It seems to me you did not start session. File1.php, print your session to get sure whether it is set or not. In file2.php also print the insert statement. it will show you the exact query

Comment: Yes I did. Still nothing is sorted out.

Comment: what is the output  in file1 & file2? what is the error?

Comment: File 1 is working fine. All details are added to the customer table. Then through a button, I'm redirecting it to cart i.e. file 2. Here I get a notice Undefined index: cid when I add anything to cart. Also, a Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in file1

Comment: Just used echo $_SESSION["cid"]; in file 2. It is also generating the same notice.

Comment: both file check "cid" (all lower case ) It seems to me you have use uppercase & lower case value. I mean to say, when you store value in session use $_SESSION["cid"] & when add in cart use the same $_SESSION["cid"]

Comment: Thank youu. That was such a blunder. I is running fine now.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.If you are happy please vote for me :)

Comment: I sure will. :) 
One more query, when I want my customer to logout, should I simply unset session?

Comment: Yes,On logout unset($_SESSION) or session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

I guess the working flow is like this:

1. customer register with your site.
2. On successful registration, you save his details to the customer table.    so in the table you have values like cid,
   username,
       password etc. (i don't see any such fields as per your table schema.
       how do you make logins?)
3. once customer logins to the site, you will validate the given details and check against your DB. if true you will store them to
       the session.    say for example,

   ```
       $_SESSION['Cid'] = the_id_of_the_logged_in_user;
       $_SESSION['username'] = the_username_of_the_logged_in_user;
   ```
4. when a user adds something to cart, you fetch the customer id ($_SESSION['Cid'] ) from the session and store to the cart table

And, thats it.

when the customer adds something to cart you can fetch the customer id from the session

```
      $customerId = $_SESSION['Cid']; //assuming that you store  it to session as $_SESSION['customerId'] = 23; (where 23 is the id of the cutomer)
```

and save to the database

```
       INSERT INTO cart (pid,cid, quantity) VALUES ('".$row{'code'}."', '".$customerId."', '".filter_input((INPUT_POST), "quantity")."')
```